# VS 2015 Android Emulator VM Images Removed

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, visual-studio-2015

After installing Xamarin updates, when I attempted to launch the Android Emulator by running(debugging) the android project I received a message that an error occurred. When I opened Hyper-V, the image was missing but several other images where there. So, in VS, I changed the emulator to one of the other listed images. When I started to debug and launch the emulator, I received the same error and that image was now missing from Hyper-V also.

The emulator is listed as a separate install from VS 2015 Community in "Programs and Features". I tried running a repair on both the emulator install and VS. I tried uninstalling the emulator, running CCleaner, rebooting, and then reinstall the emulator. The images still are missing from Hyper-V and I get the same error when trying to debug the project.

I'm currently reinstalling VS 2015 Community with little faith that it will fix the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed after the following:

1. Remove All Hyper-V virtual switches - go to Hyper-V > Virtual switch manager > Remove all virtual switches
2. Run XdeCleanup.exe - In my case: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.14393.0"
3. Repair Android SDK - go to Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android > Change and hit "Repair"
4. Start cmd.exe with Admin rights
5. bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
6. Restart pc
7. Run Visual Studio as Administrator